# Get all module test summary in the end using maven goals

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am using maven in my project it has multiple submodules in it.
The pom in folder structure looks like this:

```
root/pom.xml
    A/pom.xml
    B/pom.xml
```

The submodule definition in the parent pom looks like below:

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

When I run `mvn test` on the root pom.

My submodules are executed in the order defined in the parent pom.
My console log looks like

```
Some Log for sub project A
...
...    
...
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 523, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Some Log for sub project B
...
...    
...
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 560, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Root Project ....................................... SUCCESS [ 3.271 s]
[INFO] A ................................................ SUCCESS [  2.001 s]
[INFO] B ................................................ SUCCESS [ 1.270 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

What I want is an aggregated test summary **in the end** something like this.

```
Some Log for sub project A
...
...    
...
Some Log for sub project B
...
...    
...
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] <---- consolidated submodule test result
[WARNING] Tests run: 523, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[WARNING] Tests run: 560, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Root Project ....................................... SUCCESS [ 3.271 s]
[INFO] A ................................................ SUCCESS [  2.001 s]
[INFO] B ................................................ SUCCESS [ 1.270 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Is this possible using maven. if yes then how?

Comment: What is the problem having not a summarazation at the end? And no does not exist... furthermore this: `My submodules are executed in the order defined in the parent pom` Do you have no dependencies between the moduls? What looks strange to me: `[WARNING] Test ...` if no tests is failed or skipped? Can you give more detauls how your pom file looks like which Maven version, JDK, surefire plugin version you are using?

Comment: > What is the problem having not a summarazation at the end?
The reason I want it in the end, is because I need to have all the test summaries in the end. Currently, the test summary is displayed just after the submodule test is executed and so I need to scroll the console to accumulate all results.
Or  I need to grep it from the whole log.  I am wondering if there is any goal to get the full test submodule summary in the end. Hope it gives more clarification.

Comment: Other details you asked
Yes Submodule B depends on A..
JDK is 11
maven 3.6.3
surefire plugin 2.21.0

Comment: Using very old stuff Maven 3.6.X ... surefire 2.21.0... Do you use a CI solution like Jenkins or alike? If so this will show the information in one go... and currently there is no way to make a summarization at the end.. I ask: ` I need to have all the test summaries in the end` Why? Just because you want to or is there a deeper request/problem behind that?